# Meaning of "alt!" in Clojure

Tags: clojure, core.async

in clojure.core.async there is a function named `alts!` to wait for a message on multiple channels. In Go this is called `select` (like select a message from multiple channels), but what is the meaning of "alt" in Clojure?

I know what the function does, but it is hard for me to remember the function name when I do not know what "alts" means?  Is it a shortcut for "alternative(s)"?

Comment: That's always been my thought. It picks the first out of a set of alt(ernatives).

Comment: It is probably short for ‘alternative(s)’. That term is at least spelled out in the [announcement](https://clojure.org/news/2013/06/28/clojure-clore-async-channels).

Comment: The names `alts!` and `alt!` probably derive from the similar `ALT` construct in the [occam programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam_(programming_language)), though Occam's `ALT` clauses are each guarded by a condition.

Comment: thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docstring for `alt!` (emphasis added):

> Makes a single **choice** between **one of several** channel operations,
>   as if by alts!

and for `alts!` (emphasis added):

> Completes at most **one of several** channel operations.

This would support the idea that "alt" is short for "alternative" or "alternatives".  In other words, make a choice of one of several alternatives.